# Can i install rear speakers on my 2018 Polo?

Tags: polo, speakers

I have a 2018 5 doors polo and it has no rear speakers.
is it possible to install rear speakers and connect them to the car's dashboard ?
because when i go to speaker settings on my car and you can choose from which speaker you want the sound to come from , there is the possibility of only the front speakers

Answer (score 1):

You can add an amplifier with front/rear speaker control.

In fact you could add tweeters, rear speakers, bass - all depends on your taste.

You might find this [link](https://www.crutchfield.com/S-W2ELNhqDjVA/learn/learningcenter/car/amplifiers/shopping_guide.html) to be useful...